# Cannot get value from channel

Tags: go

I insert some values to channel. after that I tried to get it out from channel but it does not get out any value and exit. Anyone know WHY?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    c := make( chan string)
    for _, s := range []string{"A", "B", "C"} {
        fmt.Println( "input : ", s)
        go func() {
            c <- s 
        }()
    }
    close( c)
    // recive
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("output", i)
    }
}
```

Expect output

```
input :  A
input :  B
input :  C
output : A
output : B
output : C
```

Current output

```
input :  A
input :  B
input :  C
```

Comment: Your program quits before it had chance to do anything else, but print 3 lines and start 3 goroutines.

Comment: you're closing the channel immediately after starting 3 routines that send to an unbuffered channel... the second routine _will_ attempt to send on a closed channel, and all 3 routines will attempt to write `C` to the channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible your channel is closed before you add the values in the channel (`close` is called before the first line of your goroutines). Then of course there will be nothing to read in the channel.
Instead of using goroutines to add values in the channel, you could switch to a buffered channel like this:

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    inputs := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    c := make(chan string, len(inputs))
    for _, s := range inputs {
        fmt.Println( "input : ", s)
        c <- s 
    }
    close(c)
    // recive
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("output", i)
    }
}
```

Or you can use a WaitGroup like this:

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    inputs := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    c := make(chan string)
    for _, s := range inputs {
        fmt.Println( "input : ", s)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(s string) {
            c <- s
            wg.Done()
        }(s)
    }
    go func(){
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    // recive
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("output", i)
    }
}
```

Comment: It was simple version of my code. I really need to use goruutine to do heavy work.

Comment: Both proposed solutions are using goroutines.

Comment: second code you proposed seems not working with this error "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to notice in your code.

First one is usage of `s` variable from for-loop in a closure.

```
go func() {
            c <- s 
        }()
```

Here you could end up with inconsistent values as you don't know when these goroutines are going to execute. For all you know, you could end up writing "C" to the channel three times. If you want to use it with separate goroutines, use it like this:

```
go func(str string) {
                c <- str 
            }(s)
```

As for values not being retrieved from the channel, channel gets closed before anything can be retrieved from it.  You can write something like this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    c := make( chan string)
    go func(){
      for _, s := range []string{"A", "B", "C"} {
        fmt.Println( "input : ", s)
        c <- s 
      }
      close( c)
    }()
    // recive
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("output", i)
    }
}
```

But even that will give you an output like this (and even this might vary) :

```
input :  A
input :  B
output A
output B
input :  C
output C
```

To get the output you wanted you will probably need to use a buffered channel and some sort of mechanism to prevent reading until everything is written to the channel. Maybe something like this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
func main() {
    c := make( chan string,3)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    for _, s := range []string{"A", "B", "C"} {
        fmt.Println( "input : ", s)
        c <- s 
    }


    go func(w *sync.WaitGroup){
      // recive
      for i := range c {
        fmt.Println("output", i)
        w.Done()
      }
    }(&wg)

    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}
```